# How to install a hook on a process created with CreateProcess?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

Here is what I tried :

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  cout << "Starting Notepad++..." << endl;
  STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
  PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

  // set the size of the structures
  ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
  startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
  ZeroMemory(&processInformation, sizeof(processInformation));

  char commandLine[] = "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\Notepad++.exe";

  // start the program up
  BOOL res = CreateProcess(NULL,   // the path
    commandLine,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
    &startupInfo,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &processInformation             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (removed extra parentheses)
    );

  if (res) {
    if (!(mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookCallback, NULL, processInformation.dwThreadId))) {
        cout << "Failed to install mouse hook :" << endl << getLastErrorAsString() << endl;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject( processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( processInformation.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( processInformation.hThread );
  } else {
    cout << "Failed to start Notepad++" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It starts Notepad++ successfully, but it fails to install the hook and GetLastError return the following error : `The parameter is incorrect.`. I have no idea which parameter is incorrect. However, the program finishes normally when I close Notepad++.

Since I start the process in the main program and the hook callback is also in the main program, I should be able to install a hook without doing any dll injection.

I haven't touched to c++ in years, and I've never been into system development, so I may be wrong in my way to do it, so can you explain to me where my error is ?

**EDIT :**
You're all telling me that I need to inject a dll to hook a specific process, but this is from the windows documentation of `SetWindowsHookEx` about the hMod parameter (3rd parameter):

> A handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure pointed to by the
>   lpfn parameter. The hMod parameter must be set to NULL if the
>   dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by the current process
>   and if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the
>   current process.

My Thread has been created by the current process and my hook procedure is inside the code of my current process, so why it doesn't work when I'm using a not low-level hook (WH_MOUSE)?

Comment: To find out about incorrect arguments, check out the documentation. But as I recall, to inject a hook in another process you need to have a DLL.

Comment: `WH_MOUSE_LL` is global hook. it can not be set to concrete thread. this is system wide

Comment: @RbMm my bad, I missed that in the documentation, any way to install a mouse hook for a specific process only?

Comment: and if you set say `WH_MOUSE` hook - when you use thread id for another process - you need provide *DLL* - which will be injected to this process, because this hook called in process context. so `hMod` must be not 0 and must be same bitness (32 or 64) as target process

Comment: you can use `WH_MOUSE` instead. and anyway this is not for process - not such option at all, but for thread or for all threads.

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate issue: You are calling `GetLastError()` too late (at least I'm assuming, that you are calling `GetLastError()`). When calling `GetLastError`, you need to call it while its return value is valid. Any interspersed function call will invalidate the return value.

Comment: Global (not process local) hooks __must__ be in a DLL as the hook code is injected into the target process.  Only DLL modules can be injected, executable can not.  You also need to have your hook registered before the CreateProcess call.  Also the 32-bit or 64-bit process type(s) must match.

Comment: @RichardCritten global only `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` called on the thread that installed the hook - code *not injected* to another processes - because this not need any `DLL`

Comment: *"My Thread has been created by the current process"* - That's not correct. `processInformation.dwThreadId` has been created by the process created by your `CreateProcess` call. That doesn't change anything, though: You do not need to provide a DLL or inject any code into any process. As clearly [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx): *"This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it."*

Comment: @IInspectable, any way to create the process directly from the current process? The hook I was looking for is `WH_MOUSE` actually, and not `WH_MOUSE_LL`, but if the the process isn't directly created by the current process as I thought it was, I need to inject dll, and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: what you mean under "direct" create process ? `CreateProcess` and do this "direct" as possible. but anyway this is new process and you need have dll if you want that hook will be called in context of target process.

Comment: else one very important point - if you call `SetWindowsHookExW` just, for new created thread - it fail - thread yet not gui thread. you need call `WaitForInputIdle(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);` first and only after this `SetWindowsHookExW`

Comment: @RbMm, it looks like I have to use a dll, my code would only works for a thread created by the current process and not another process.

Comment: if you set not 0 for thread id - hook will be only for this thread (if hook allow be per thread). if you use 0 in place thread - dll will be injected to multiple gui processes, when condition fire. but for new start process - you call `SetWindowsHookEx` too early. before thread became gui thread. you need wait in `WaitForInputIdle`

Comment: *if the dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by the current process* - this mean if thread *executed* in current process, not created by. bad documentation

Comment: with `WaitForInputIdle` the last error message became `Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle`, _this mean if thread executed in current process, not created by._, yes it's surely the reason, I'll inject a dll. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: @RbMm: [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/?p=14483/).

Comment: @IInspectable - this is obvious from `WaitForInputIdle` take handle for process, not for thread. but from another side we not need  iddle input at all. simply `SetWindowsHookExW` fail if called for not gui thread. we need wait until thread became gui thread - on first gui call to kernel. for first thread, if exe static link to user32.dll or gdi32.dll - this is in process intitialization - exactly on call `NtGdiInit` (before this set hook failed, after this is ok). use `WaitForInputIdle` not mandatory but enough for success call `SetWindowsHookExW` for first thread in process

Comment: this is not exact solution, but i dont know - how exactly wait for moment when thread converted to gui thread. are you know better solution ? anyway if we just call `SetWindowsHookExW` after createprocess - call almost 100% fail - due new process thread yet not call any NtGdi* or NtUser* api

Comment: `WaitForInputIdle` works well for me

Comment: @RbMm: [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/winevents-collision169) is the only infrastructure that allows you to identify, whether the window you are interested in is about to get created. This is not the earliest time you can install a hook, but it is the earliest time to install a hook on the correct thread.

Comment: @FrançoisMENTEC: Unless you are writing DDE code, `WaitForInputIdle` doesn't work for you, because it wasn't implemented to provide a solution to your use case. That's explained in the blog entry I posted, and articles it links to.

Comment: @IInspectable - but i say not about some window, but about moment, after this we can call `SetWindowsHookExW` - this is just after thread converted to gui thread.

Comment: @IInspectable - and i just test `SetWinEventHook` -the same story - if call it for not gui thread - we get error `1444` - *Invalid thread identifier.*. only after thread became gui thread - call is ok. so if you call `SetWinEventHook` just after createprocess call, without any wait - this call fail too. or need do this for all threads in system - wait for some known window creation, or wait when concrete thread became gui. `WaitForInputIdle` not do this exactly, but effective in practic

Comment: @RbMm: So then, set up a global WinEvents hook. You already know the process ID you are interested in, and thus can filter on that in your hook callback (using [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx)). Added bonus: This will also provide you with the *correct* thread ID, in case your window of interest isn't created on the process' primary thread (which `PROCESS_INFORMATION::dwThreadId` returns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low-level hooks are executed, before the destination of the input has even been evaluated. That's the reason, why low-level hooks need to be global, as explained in the documentation for [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx). You cannot pass a non-zero value for the *dwThreadId* parameter.

Comment: Ok, but why it doesn't work when I use `WH_MOUSE` either?

Comment: @FrançoisMENTEC: It's not clear, what you mean by *"it doesn't work"*. But for a [WH_MOUSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644988.aspx) you need to run a message loop.

Comment: Sorry, by it doesn't work I mean that SetWindowsHookEx return NULL, I know about the message loop. And I still get this useless `The parameter is incorrect.` message.

Comment: @FrançoisMENTEC: Since I cannot see the code that's failing, I can only guess: Make sure you heed the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx), particularly the documentation on *lpfn*: *"If the* dwThreadId *parameter [...] specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the* lpfn *parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL."*